# How to upload laravel project on remote server

Tags: linux, laravel, ubuntu, remote-server, botman

I'm trying to install new laravel project via ssh connection on remote server based on ubuntu. I've faced following problem:

[image]

This project requires php 7.2 zip extension I guess. But I've already had php 7.2.

[image]

Can someone help me with this?

P.S. I've tried every command like sudo apt-get install php7*- and etc...

Comment: which php version is enabled? check `php -v`, and make file with php ext. add code `<?php echo phpinfo(); ?>` check both version are same?

Comment: `PHP 7.2.26-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Dec 18 2019 14:57:40) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.26-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies`

Comment: And what about `<?php echo phpinfo(); ?>` ?

Comment: Yes, I checked. They are the same `PHP Version 7.2.26-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1`

Comment: did you install composer ?

Comment: yes, i have composer